# Is it okay to put the word "even" in a sentence beginning with even though?

Tags: grammar

Is it okay to say that "I thank you for your patience, even though even I myself am not happy with the pace of making the change.

Comment: I don't know about others, to me this sentence is a bit unidiomatic. First, why say *"I thank you for your patience"* instead of *"Thank you for being patient?"* Second, even if *"even though even I"* is grammatically correct, it sounds very unnatural. Third, *"the pace of making the change"* is unclear. Are you saying *"with how things are progressing"* or *"with the pace at which things are moving/progressing?"* Fourth, I think *"myself"* needs to have a pair of commas around it.

Comment: The sentence is *grammatical*, but it's a little awkward.

Comment: If you are thanking me for my patience, your happiness or lack thereof with the pace is irrelevant.

Comment: In addition to the redundant usage of the word *even*, there is a more subtle issue with your sentence and how you are using *even though*.  *Even though* is intended to introduce a contrasting phrase but the last half of your sentence does not contrast with the first.  For example, *I thank you for your patience, even though mine has run out.*  Or perhaps, *Many of you are happy with the pace of change, even though I am not.*  As you have used it, it's a bit clumsy.

Answer (score -1):

> I thank you for your patience, even though even I myself am not happy with the pace of making the change.

That sentence is fine. You can, indeed, use "even though" at the start of a clause. You can also remove "even" to make the *contradiction* the 2nd clause has to the 1st clause a little weaker. You can also flip the 2 clauses, though in this particular sentence you gave, I think it sounds better as it is, not flipped.

Comment: I would not call the sentence fine.  *Even*, as used, denotes an emphasis in comparison.  *Even though even I* is redundant.  You only need say *Even though I* or *Though even I*.  Both mean the same thing as the redundancy.